# How to calculate net price per product and also totals for all the products in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

[Purchase order html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J6Hc.png)

an someone please help me with the best way to calculate net price per product and total of all products,also with multiple rows is the best way to extract data and then store it in the sqlalchemy database,
The date format is dd-mm-yyyy,is it necessary to convert to the sqlalchemy format

```
def purchase_order():
    
    print("Entering purchase_order function")  # Add this line to verify the function is entered
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Extract form data
        date = request.form.get('Date', None)
        print(f"Date from form: {date}")

        
        

        # Convert date to the desired format ('yyyy-mm-dd')
      
        serial_number = request.form.getlist('serial_number')
        print(f'Serial number is {serial_number}')
        supplier_name = request.form.get('Supplier_Name')
        print(f'Supplier name is {supplier_name}')
        supplier_address = request.form.get('address')
        product_name = request.form.getlist('product_name')
        ean_code= request.form.getlist('EAN_CODE')
        color = request.form.getlist('color')
        power = request.form.getlist('power')
        label = request.form.getlist('label')
        packing = request.form.getlist('packing')
        qty = float(request.form.getlist('Qty')) if request.form.getlist('Qty') is not None else 0.0
        unit_price = float(request.form.getlist('Unit_Price')) if request.form.getlist('Unit_Price') is not None else 0.0
        net_price = float(request.form.getlist('Net_Price')) if request.form.getlist('Net_Price') is not None else 0.0
        total = float(request.form.get('hidden_total')) if request.form.get('hidden_total') is not None else 0.0

        

        purchase_order = PurchaseOrder(
                serial_number=serial_number,
                product_name=product_name,
                date=date,
                color=color,
                power=power,
                label=label,
                ean_code=ean_code,
                packing=packing,
                qty=qty,
                supplier_name=supplier_name,
                supplier_address=supplier_address,
                unit_price=unit_price,
                net_price=net_price,
                total=total,           
            
            )

            # Add instances to the session and commit changes to the database
        try:
            db.session.add(purchase_order)
            db.session.commit()
            flash("Order added successfully!", "success")
            return redirect(url_for('success.success', total=total))
        except Exception as e:
            db.session.rollback()  # Rollback changes in case of an error
            print(f"Error inserting data into the database: {e}")
    return render_template('purchase_order.html')
'''
```